# AngularJS currency filter in pounds

Tags: angularjs

i'm learning AngularJS and in the tutorial i'm following we had to use the currency filter, i noticed that this changes, for example 10, into $10.00.

How do i do this for English pounds?

```
   <p class="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   {{ price | currency:'Symbol for pound'}}
```

Place your symbol for pound over here in ' '

Answer (score 5):

angular currency filter take one optionnal parameter and it's the currency symbol.

With this information, your snippet will look like this :

```
<p class="price">{{product.price|currency:"£"}}</p>
```

[AngualJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Hope it's help

Answer (score 1):

You Should really look at the Angularjs Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

The format your looking for is

```
{{amount | currency:'£'}}
```

[This](https://jquerytipsntricks.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/using-currency-formats-in-angularjs/)  tutorial discuss the currency filter in detail.

Comment: I have now found the documentation, thank you very much, I shall read through carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can add you symbol and fractionSize like this:

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

for now your solution is:

```
<p class="price">{{ price | currency : '£'}}</p>
```

More detail [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)